# How to use HTTP Node.js requests in Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, http, get, angular-universal

I would like to move AngularJS project to Angular Universal.

In AngularJS I had $http requests using PHP. For example I had the following code in Services:

```
this.getNewItems = function () {

    var request = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "PHP/newitems.php",
        params: {
            number: "3"
        }
    });

    return ( request.then(handleSuccess, handleError) );

};
```

Now as I use Node.js with Universal I would like to use Http request with Node.js.

So in component's constructor I should use the construction:

```
export class HomeComponent {
  mydata: any = {};

  constructor(http:Http) {

    http.get('??????').subscribe(data => {
      this.mydata = data;

    });
  }
}
```

If I would use JSON-file then I have found many examples like this:

```
http.get('test.json').subscribe(data => {
    this.mydata = data;
});
```

However all my data is in existing MySQL database. So I would like to understand how I can reach my data in database.

I have already installed npm MySql component by

> npm install mysql

I have found that a connection with Node.js is setting by:

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'host',
        user     : 'user',
        password : 'password',
        database : 'dbname'
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        // in case of error
        if(err){
            console.log(err.code);
            console.log(err.fatal);
        }
    });
```

If I use this connection code in Component's constructor then some errors return, like

```
ERROR in ./~/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net'
```

So how I can integrate the connection code with http.get() request?

Thanks a lot.

**Addition**: now I came to this (it concerns my starter project for Angular Universal https://github.com/angular/universal-starter):

1. In **Component** I use the following code:

   export class HomeComponent {

   ```
       mydata:any = [];

       constructor(public model: ModelService) {

        this.model.get('/api/getmydata')
           .subscribe(data => {

             this.mydata = data;
             console.log("My data: " + this.mydata);
       });
       } 
   }
   ```

2.In **backend/api.ts** I've added:

```
router.route('/getmydata')
      .get(function(req, res) {

        setTimeout(function() {
          res.json(Mydata);
        }, 0);
}
```

If **Mydata** is a JSON then all works properly and I receive the data. However I would like to connect to MySQL database. So I add a connection code:

```
router.route('/getmydata')
          .get(function(req, res) {

        var mysql = require('mysql');

        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'root',
          password : 'root',
          database : 'mydatabase',
          port: '8889'
        });

        connection.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error connecting to DB: " + err);
            throw err;
          }
        });
...

}
```

Here I receive errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
        at Protocol._enqueue (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Angular2/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:152:5)
...
```

Then

```
Error connecting to DB: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
```

If anyone knows how to fix the connection to database I would highly appreciate the advice.

Comment: Which bundling tool do you use for bundle the application? is it webpack?

Comment: I use starter webpack: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Answer (score 1):

When bundling with node as target, webpack provides an option to customize node environment. [The default configuration is:](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/)

```
node: {
  console: false,
  global: true,
  process: true,
  Buffer: true,
  __filename: "mock",
  __dirname: "mock",
  setImmediate: true
}
```

As you can notice, webpack's default node environment configuration doesn't take libraries such as 'net' under consideration. Adding net library to node environment properties in your server webpack configuration **(which is targeted to node)** should help (probably webpack.config.js):

```
node: {
  // your existing props
  net: false
}
```

The reason I chose to set the value to `false` [is trying to follow the code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/node/NodeSourcePlugin.js#L17) that resolves these properties. [The possible values are documented, but there's not enough documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node) regarding what each value means in case of custom properties. Basically (as far as I understand it), `false` means there's no need in a browser version or a mock of 'net', you need the module itself because the bundle runs in node.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined ...
```

may occur if **Zone.js** has an incorrect version or doesn't install properly.

I have found that I received a Warning:

```
angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.21 but none was installed.
```

So the command to **install Zone.js** is:

```
npm install zone.js@0.6.21
```

Now I am receiving the data from MySQL database successfully.

The complete code is:

```
    router.route('/newvideos')
          .get(function(req, res) {

            var mysql = require('mysql');

            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
              host     : 'localhost',
              user     : 'root',
              password : 'root',
              database : 'myDB',
              port: '8889'
            });

            connection.connect(function(err) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Error connecting to DB: " + err);
                throw err;
              }
            });

            connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function(err, rows, fields) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Error executing query: " + err);
                throw err;
              }

              connection.end();

              setTimeout(function() {
                res.json(rows);
              }, 0);
         });

     })
```

**HOWEVER!!!**
I have found that after this the server rendering with using *ngFor stops working!

In HTML-template I have seen only:

```
 <!--template bindings={}-->
```

I played with this error on simple JSON return, without connection to database. 
So I have found that even if I return JSON server rendering stops working.
Then I have installed Zone.js without version:

```
npm install zone.js
```

and again started returning JSON. At this case server rendering began working properly.
But when I have started making connection to MySQL the first original error has occured.

In my case now I have either a connection to MySQL or server rendering. Not both at one time.

If anyone knows how to fix this I'll appreciate the advice. Thank you.

**Addition:** I have found the solution. See [Due to Zone.js in Angular Universal server rendering stops working. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659236/due-to-zone-js-in-angular-universal-server-rendering-stops-working-how-to-fix)